# script in script webpart find a specific image in an image library in sharepoint

Tags: picture-library, image, script, sharepoint-library

I want to write my costume photo slider in script editor web part.
 I already have the script for basic photo slider, now I want to use a specific images in an image library.
What is a quick easy script to get images with specific value of a column, like news : true, from an image library?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you only need the URL to the files in the image library.

You can use the JSOM to get items in javascript. To only retrieve items where the column News has the value 'true' you can use a CAML query.

More information including example scripts: [JSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx), [CAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx)